# Can Hom-Lie algebras be seen as an $\Omega$-algebras?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

An $\Omega$-algebra over a field $K$ is a $K$-algebra $A$ with a set of multilinear operators $\Omega$, where $\Omega=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \Omega_{m}$ and each $\Omega_{m}$ is a set of $m$-array multilinear operators on $A$. On the other side, let consider the definition of Hom-Lie algebras as follows:

A Hom-algebra $L$ is called a Hom-Lie algebra, if $L$ is anticommutative as an algebra. i.e., $[x,y]=-[y,x]$ and the following identityholds
$$ [[x,y],\alpha(z)]+[[z,x],\alpha(y)]+[[y,z],\alpha(x)]=0, $$
for any $x,y,z \in L$ and $\alpha: L \to L$ is a linear map.

Can Hom-Lie algebras be seen as a $\Omega$-algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Hom-Lie algebras can be considered in the framework of multiple operated algebras. We have finished this paper and we will pose it on Arxiv in the next time. Please see our recent paper [Matching Rota-Baxter algebras, matching dendriform algebras and matching pre-Lie algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.10577)

for the relative topies. What's more, the Grobner-Shirshov basis of these  algebraic structures have been done by our another paper.

Comment: Thank you for your information about interesting article. Regarding Groebner-Shirshov basis, may you send me the link of that as well?

Comment: @user118746, can you send me your email, I will give you some details.